# How to focus invalid fields with jQuery validate?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

There is [`focusInvalid`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions) option, which is `true` by default. But it works only when form submission happens. If I validate the form with [`valid`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/valid) method, then it doesn't work. So the question is how to focus invalid field when `valid` is used?

Please see [this demo](http://jsbin.com/ayupob) to see the difference. Just press buttons there.

Comment: @Evan, don't you like jsbin? You can modify that as well - http://jsbin.com/ayupob/edit#javascript,html

Answer (score 56, accepted):

First of all you need to save your validator to a variable so you can use it in the click handler:

```
var validator = $("#test-form").validate({ /* settings */ });
```

Then in the validate handler, you can manually call the `focusInvalid` function from the `validator` variable:

```
  $("#validate").click(function() {
        if ($("#test-form").valid()) 
              alert("Valid!");
        else
              validator.focusInvalid();

        return false;
  });
```

[**Example**](http://jsbin.com/ayupob/2/edit)

Answer (score 70):

With the `invalidHandler` you can set focus to the first element that fails:

```
$("#form").validate({
    onfocusout: false,
    invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
        var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
        if (errors) {                    
            validator.errorList[0].element.focus();
        }
    } 
});
```

Comment: jQuery validate selects the first invalid element **or the last focused invalid element**. Your code is the only I've found that dodges this annoyance and always selects the first. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah there is a lot a snafus that affect jquery.validates focus handling. By itself it works like a top but when you start adding in responsive designs and more jquery scripts, the focus can get somewhat off. Nice script, thanks for posting it.

Comment: +1 for this option, couldn't find it anywhere. BTW, a small tip: also do `validator.lastActive = validator.errorList[0].element;` to avoid focussing on two elements.. this was something I faced with `end date` field as last active and `start date` as first invalid field, datepickers popped up on both fields (of course both were invalid). Cheers!!